# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have imported maven project in eclipse but I got an error in pom.xml (Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile).)

Below is my pom.xml code. Please let me know how to resolve this error?

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>qaclickacademy</groupId>
  <artifactId>Mavenjava</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Mavenjava</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: can you please error that you got?

Comment: The error is  Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin